# How two synchronize infinite UIScrollViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to build an infinite timeline with Xcode 6.3. I have two synchronized, infinite ScrollViews. One Scroll view shows the content and the other shows the days. The Scroll View with days scrolls only in x-direction. The content scroll view scrolls in both direction. The day-scrollview should always be visible (as caption).

I used the Apple StreetScroller approach for infinite scrolling. For synchronization i use the following code:

```
- (void)setSynchronizedScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollview
{    
    // don't retain the watched view, because we assume that it will
    // be retained by the view hierarchy for as long as we're around.
    synchronizedScrollView = scrollview;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = synchronizedScrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.x = self.contentOffset.x;
    [synchronizedScrollView setContentOffset:offset];
}
```

The two scroll views don't scroll synchronously? What would be the best approach to solute this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Add this delegate to your class: `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Obj-C:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Swift:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

Override this function and return true

Comment: This doesn't help... The function is called but the two ScrollViews don't scroll synchronously. I added it in a subclass of UIScrollView (both scroll view are of this type). Thanks for your help!

Comment: you did return it in every case right? and implemented the delegate? without delegate it wont work